# no X-Forwarded-For with Traefik 2 on bare metal Kubernetes with ClusterIP Service and kube-keepalive-vip

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, x-forwarded-for

My setup is a bare metal cluster running Kubernetes 1.17. I'm using Traefik 2(.3.2) as a reverse proxy and to get failover for my machines I use `kube-keepalive-vip` [1].

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-keepalived-vip-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  172.111.222.33: kube-system/traefik2-ingress-controller
```

Therefore my traefik service is of default type cluster IP and references an external IP provided by the `kube-keepalive-vip` service:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik2-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik2-ingress-controller
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      name: webs
      port: 443
  externalIPs:
    - 172.111.222.33
```

This works as it is. Now I want to restrict some of my applications to be accessible only from a specific subnet inside my network. Since my requests are handled by `kube-keepalive-vip` and also `kube-proxy`, the client IP in my requests is not the one of the actual client anymore. But as far as I got the documentation `kube-proxy` is setting the real ip in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. So my Middleware looks like this:

```yaml
internal-ip-whitelist:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
      - 10.0.0.0/8 # my subnet
      - 60.120.180.240 # my public ip
    ipStrategy:
      depth: 2 # take second entry from X-Forwarded-For header
```

Now each request to  the ingresses this middleware is attached to is rejected. I checked the Traefik logs and saw, that the requests contain some `X-Forwarded-*` headers, but there is no `X-Forwarded-For` :(

Has anyone any experience with this and can point me to my error? Is there probably something wrong with my Kubernetes setup? Or is there something missing in my `kube-keepalive-vip` config?

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://github.com/aledbf/kube-keepalived-vip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone stumbling upon this, I managed to fix my problem in the meantime.

The main problem is `kube-proxy`. By default all services are routed through it. And, depending on your CNI provider (I use `flannel`), the information of your calling client is lost there.

K8s provides a way around that by setting the `.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#aws-nlb-support). But this is not supported for `ClusterIP` services.

So I got around that by using MetalLB (https://metallb.universe.tf/) which provides load balancing for *bare metal* clusters. After setting it up with my virtual IP that was assigned to the keepalived container before, I configured the traefik service with type `LoadBalancer` and requested the one IP I have in MetalLB.